# Driver [keycloak] not supported in laravel 6

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to use socialiteproviders/keycloak 5.1.1 for my laravel 6 project. Followed all steps of https://packagist.org/packages/socialiteproviders/keycloak#5.1.1

But it shows Driver [keycloak] not supported by following code

```
public function handleRedirect()
{
    return Socialite::driver('keycloak')->redirect();
}
```

Comment: Are you sure to add listening event in EventServiceProvider?

Comment: added
\SocialiteProviders\Manager\SocialiteWasCalled::class => [
        // ... other providers
        \SocialiteProviders\Keycloak\KeycloakExtendSocialite::class.'@handle',
    ],

Comment: Can you send your $listener variable from event service provider file?

Comment: protected $listen = [
        Registered::class => [
            SendEmailVerificationNotification::class,
        ],
        \SocialiteProviders\Manager\SocialiteWasCalled::class => [
            // ... other providers
            \SocialiteProviders\Keycloak\KeycloakExtendSocialite::class.'@handle',
        ],
    ];

Comment: is it ? could not understand properly

Comment: What is the exact error you are getting?

Comment: Showing Driver [keycloak] not supported

Comment: Did you add the appropriate service provider as described in https://socialiteproviders.com/usage/#_2-service-provider

Comment: @Hasnat Thanks a lot. Now it's working . How can I receive data after call back. Also please through a answer so that I can approve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [setup guide](https://socialiteproviders.com/usage/#_2-service-provider) You need to Socialite Providers in your service providers. Then the different providers will be available.

```
'providers' => [
    // a whole bunch of providers
    // remove 'Laravel\Socialite\SocialiteServiceProvider',
    \SocialiteProviders\Manager\ServiceProvider::class, // add
];
```